# Unique number generation in C#

Tags: c#, unique

I have a bulk insert of around 100,000 records that is going to a oracle table having one unique value column. This bulk insert will happen twice or thrice a day up to many years(Never ending).

Need a robust mechanism to generate unique numbers of unique value column. I am building the dataset to commit to database at once.

Previously I created sequence in oracle, and while building the dataset rows, hitting the database, getting a new sequence number and putting into that column. But it is giving performance issues as for 100,000 records, 100,000 database hits will be needed.

Any other method. This unique value column is varchar2 and max length is 20

Comment: How much is a Lakh? Not everyone here is Indian.

Comment: Apparently it's 100,000. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention that the numbers must be sequential (1..n) so perhaps you could generate GUIDs and represent them in a compact way. In the long run you might encounter collisions, and in that case you can generate a new GUID.

The only problem I see is that you'd need 25 chars to represent the GUID in Base64 (23 if you strip the padding).

Comment: GUID would be good but if multiple sessions are running in parallel and accessing the same function that generates the GUID, then there will be a huge duplication and we can not compare whether the newly generated unique number is there in table or not because of performance overhead

Comment: number need not to be sequential. The only constraint in 20 character word should be unique(like GUID). But the DLL in which I will put the GUID generator function, can be accessed in multiple sessions and in multiple sessions, it will generate duplicate GUIDs

Comment: GUIDs are *globally unique*, across machines and sessions (provided you use the same algorithm), even if generated at the same exact moment. We have a system that uses GUIDs as primary keys in a data store. A table has several millions rows, inserted by multiple machines running in parallel, and we never hit a collision over the past 2.5 years.

Comment: So how you generated those GUIDs. Any code/algorithm? Will GUID.NEWID() have same in dependency across machines and sessions that you talked about in above comment.

Comment: Read the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create an [autonumber sequence](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/autonumber.html) using triggers if you're only doing a bulk insert?

Comment: that means for each record, we need to hit database to get a unique number. Acc to this, so many times we need to hit db that is in-acceptable. I want to do it in .NET

Comment: @AkkiJ the database will generate the unique number for you automaticaly with very little overhead, you dont state in your question that you will need to use that ID again immediately, so after the Bulk import is done, just do a query to select all the rows you need.

Answer (score -2):

you can generate new sequence GUID and take its 20 characters instead of '-' symbol and insert into database. This GUID in not user friendly so no one use can remember this easily....

Comment: Gaurav, GUID is not fit if your GUID generating function is accessed in multiple sessions running in parallel as it will generate duplicate GUIDs if seperate sessions are accessing same GUID generator function